# ¿Cómo establecer una condicional cuando una propiedad es visibility hidden y otra condicional cuando está con display none?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Quisiera saber si es posible armar una sentencia *if/else* cuando tengo una clase que en la hoja de estilos le pongo `visibility : hidden` y otra clase con `display : none`, ya que en el javascript estoy poniendo un *if* de prueba pero se entra aunque en la condicional le cambio el valor de la propiedad.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   const ventanaBuscador = document.getElementById('ventanaBuscador');
   if ($('.ventana-login').css('visibility','visible')) {
       /*(ventanaBuscador.style.display='block') ||*/
       console.log("SI");
   }
}
```

Le puse como constante ya que la variable la voy a utilizar para otra función.

Como pueden ver trate de poner esos pedazos de código de argumento en el *if* pero me ingresa independientemente de lo establecido en el css:

```
.ventana-login{
      background: #0033CC;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      border-radius: 3px;
      width: 304px;
      padding: 30px 15px;
      text-align: center;
      position: fixed;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
      visibility: hidden;
      z-index: 100;
}
.ventana_buscador{
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
      font-size: 13px;
      transition: all 600ms;
      z-index: 75;
      display: none;
}
```

En el html está:

```
<div class="ventana_buscador" id="ventanaBuscador"> ... </div>
```

Comment: El if te va a fallar porque el selector siempre encuentra al elemento y devuelve true, el metodo css se aplica despues de hacer la busqueda. Me parece que lo que quieres es manipular elementos segun se haga scroll en la ventana?

Comment: En parte si ya que si tengo una ventana emergente abierta se supone que como tengo el un cobertor que no permite manipular los botones que tengo detrás y lo que quiero hacer con el "if" es que cuando se haga scroll y si esta abierta alguna ventana esa parte agregarle un "z-index" para que se mantenga por detrás del cobertor

Answer (score 2):

Según he ententido, lo que quieres es comprobar si el estilo está con `visibility : hidden` o  con `display : none`.

Si es así, tu puedes acceder directamente al style del elemento.

```
if ($('.ventana-login').style.visibility == 'hidden') {
      
   console.log("SI");
}
```

Comment: Carmen gracias por tu respuesta pero esta sentencia no se la puede ver en consola, sale un mensaje de que no se puede leer la propiedad de un indefinido.

Comment: cierto, he puesto directamente sobre la clase css y no sobre el objeto que quieres ver su propiedad. Si lo que quieres es ver si tu ventanaBuscador tiene una propiedad u otra tendrías que sustituir en el if ventana-login por ventanaBuscador.   if ($('.ventana-login').style.visibility == 'hidden') {
      
   console.log("SI");
}